# `find` with multiple `-name` and `-exec` executes only the last matches of `-name`

Tags: find

When I'm using

```
find . -type f -name "*.htm*" -o -name "*.js*" -o -name "*.txt"
```

it finds all the types of file. But when I add `-exec` at the end:

```
find . -type f -name "*.htm*" -o -name "*.js*" -o -name "*.txt" -exec sh -c 'echo "$0"' {} \;
```

it seems it only prints `.txt` files. What am I doing wrong?

Note: using MINGW (Git Bash)

Answer (score 170, accepted):

```
find . -type f -name "*.htm*" -o -name "*.js*" -o -name "*.txt"
```

is short for:

```
find . '('                                      \
           '(' -type f -a -name "*.htm*" ')' -o \
           '(' -name "*.js*" ')' -o             \
           '(' -name "*.txt" ')'                \
       ')' -a -print
```

That is, because no *action* predicate is specified (only *conditions*), a `-print` action is implicitly added for the files that match the conditions.

(and, by the way, that would print non-regular `.js` files (the `-type f` only applies to `.htm` files)).

While:

```
find . -name "*.htm*" -o -name "*.js*" -o -name "*.txt" \
  -exec sh -c 'echo "$0"' {} \;
```

is short for:

```
find . '(' -type f -a -name "*.htm*" ')' -o \
       '(' -name "*.js*" ')' -o \
       '(' -name "*.txt" -a -exec sh -c 'echo "$0"' {} \; ')'
```

For `find` (like in many languages), *AND* (`-a`; implicit when omitted) has precedence over *OR* (`-o`), and adding an explicit action predicate (here `-exec`) cancels the `-print` implicit action seen above.

Here, you want:

```
find . '(' -name "*.htm*" -o -name "*.js*" -o -name "*.txt" ')' \
       -type f \
       -exec sh -c 'echo "$0"' {} \;
```

Or:

```
find . '(' -name "*.htm*" -o -name "*.js*" -o -name "*.txt" ')' \
       -type f \
       -exec sh -c '
         for i do
           echo "$i"
         done' sh {} +
```

To avoid running one `sh` per file.

(`-type f` being more expensive than `-name` as it potentially implies retrieving information from the inode, is best put *after* though some `find` implementations do reorder the checks internally for optimisation).

Comment: In some of those sh -c uses, you need to add the zeroth argument for sh (though in others you included it already).

Answer (score 41):

It is the implied brackets. Add explicit brackets. `\(` `\)`

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.htm*" -o -name "*.js*" -o -name "*.txt" \) -exec sh -c 'echo "$0"' {} \;
```

or using xargs ( I like xargs I find it easier, but apparently not as portable).

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.htm*" -o -name "*.js*" -o -name "*.txt" \) -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 echo
```