# find: prune does not ignore specified path

Tags: bash, find

I need to exclude `.git` from my `find` search. To achive that, I am using the `-path ./.git -prune` switch:

```
$ find . -path ./.git -prune -o \( -type f -o -type l -o -type d \) | grep '.git'
./.git
```

However, even though this skips the contents of the .git directory, it lists the directory itself. It works when I add `-path ./.git -prune -o -print -a`

```
find . -path ./.git -prune -o -print -a \( -type f -o -type l -o -type d \) | grep '.git'
```

Why is this necessary. I thought that both commands should have same output. The second syntax is quite ugly.

Comment: You need a `-print`, otherwise the implicit `-print` applies to the whole condition

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/102191/22565

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to exclude a directory from the find command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/350085/21471)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `man` page for `find` gives:

```
-prune True; if the file is a directory, do not  descend  into  it.  If
      -depth  is  given,  false;  no  effect.  Because -delete implies
      -depth, you cannot usefully use -prune and -delete together.
```

So in the first example it is not so that `-path ./.git -prune` is untrue and therefore the default action (`-print`) would not be called, hence the line is printed.

Answer (score 31):

I was confused as to why pruned directories were being printed by the `find` command, too, and some other intricate details of how `-prune` worked, but was able to figure it out with a few examples.

To run the examples below create the following directories and files.

```
mkdir aa
mkdir bb
touch file1
touch aa/file1
touch bb/file3
```

To create this structure:

```
$ tree

.
├── aa
│   └── file1
├── bb
│   └── file3
└── file1
```

Now use find to look for directories named `aa`. No problem here.

```
$ find . -type d -name aa
./aa
```

Look for all directories other than aa and we get the current directory **`.`** and `./bb`, which also makes sense.

```
$ find . -type d ! -name aa
.
./bb
```

So far so good, but when we use `-prune`, find returns the directory we are pruning, which initially confused me because I was expecting it to return all the other directories and not the one being pruned.

```
$ find . -type d -name aa -prune
./aa
```

The reason why it returns the directory being pruned is explained, not in the `-prune` section of the man pages as indicated in [Timo's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109993), but in the `EXPRESSIONS` section:

> If  the  expression contains no actions other than `-prune`, 
>   `-print` is performed on all files for which the expression is true.

which means that, since the expression matches the `aa` directory name, then the expression will evaluate to true and it will be printed because find implicitly adds a `-print` at the end of the entire command. It won't add a `-print`, however, if you purposely add the action `-o -print` to the end yourself:

```
find . -type d -name aa -prune -o -print
.
./file1
./bb
./bb/file3
```

Here the find command DOES NOT add an implicit `-print` anymore, and so the directory we are pruning (`aa`) won't get printed.

So finally, if we add a clause that searches for files with a filename pattern of `file*` after the `-o`, then you have to put a `-print` at the end of that second clause like this:

```
find . \( -type d -name aa -prune \) -o \( -type f -name 'file*' -print \)
./file1
./bb/file3
```

The reason why this works is the same: If you don't put a `-print` in the second clause, then since there is no action other than the `-prune` action, find will add a `-print` automatically at THE END of the command, causing the `-prune` clause to print the pruned directory:

```
find . \( \( -type d -name aa -prune \) -o \( -type f -name 'file*' \) \) -print
./aa
./file1
./bb/file3
```

In general, you need to place the `-print` command in the second clause. If you place it in the middle like the original poster did, it will not work correctly because the files being pruned will be printed immediately and second clause will not get a chance to pick the files it wants:

```
find . \( -type d -name aa -prune -o -print \) -o \( -type f -name 'file*' \)
.
./file1
./bb
./bb/file3
```

So unfortunately, the original poster got the command wrong above by placing the `-print` in the wrong place. It might have worked for his specific case, but it doesn't work in the general case.

There are thousands of people who have difficulties understanding how `-prune` works. 

The `find` man page should be updated in order to prevent the neverending worldwide confusion about this command.

Comment: My man page (Arch Linux, `find-4.6.0`) says, "If  the  whole expression contains no actions other than -prune or -print, -print is performed on all files for which the whole expression is true." But works as you describe.

Answer (score 1):

from `man` page,

> To ignore a whole directory tree, use -prune rather than checking every file in the  tree.   For  example,  to skip the directory `src/emacs' and all files and directories under it, and print the names of the other files found, do something like this:

```
find . -path ./src/emacs -prune -o -print
```

So, may be you can use:

```
find . -path ./.git -prune -o -print
```

This will not lists the `.git` directory.

to specific a file name, you can do like this:

```
find . -path ./.git -prune , -name filename
```

Please notice the `,` comma operator.

Comment: can you please elaborate a little bit more on the comma (`,`) because i never saw it used for `find` and it is not even mentioned at the man page.

Comment: @DJCrashdummy, please search `OPERATORS` section in the man page. refer this page: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html

Comment: if i understood your answer correct, the result of `find "$HOME/" -path "$HOME/.*" -prune -o \( -empty -print \)` and `find "$HOME/" -path "$HOME/.*" -prune , -empty` should be the same... but i do get with the later still empty dot files & dot folders in the output!?!

Comment: what's different?

Answer (score 0):

To list all files except those in .git I use this command

```
find -type f -not -path './.git/*'
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to ignore specific paths in `find` command is to use `find` with exclude option of `ls` command as mentioned below. i have folders `mumbai, dubai,tokyo, delhi, london, rome` in /var/www/html. will exclude here london and tokyo folder to list all files from rest of folders.

```
ls /var/www/html |grep  -v 'london\|tokyo'  #ls exclude  example is mentioned here.
```

find exclude tip is shown below:-

```
find $(ls /var/www/html |grep  -v 'london\|tokyo' ) -type f #run above exclude option with find command as mentioned here.
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a quick and dirty alternative:

```
find | fgrep -v /.git
```

I simply can't remember `find`'s complex syntax...