# Is it possible to exclude a directory from the find command?

Tags: find

I am using `find -type f` command to recursively find all files from a certain starting directory. However, I would like to have some directories prevented from entering and extracting names of files inside. So basically I am looking for something like:

```
find . -type f ! -name "avoid_this_directory_please"
```

Is there a functioning alternative to this?

Comment: There's a [dozen questions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=find+%22-prune%22) on the troubles with using `-prune`: it can be a bit confusing.  Also [this on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1489405/6372809) describes why it's such an annoying thing to use.

Comment: Even if this is a dupe the best answer here is clearer than the best answer on the "correct" question.

Comment: Hmm, "find -prune isn't working for me" sure sounds different from "how do I exclude directories from find output?" to me ...

Comment: @SamB Agreed, this can't possibly be a duplicate.

Answer (score 56):

This is what the `-prune` option is for:

```bsh
find . -type d -name 'avoid_this_directory_please' -prune -o \
    -type f -print
```

You may interpret the above as "if there's a directory called `avoid_this_directory_please`, don't enter it, otherwise, if it's a regular file, print its pathname."

You may also prune the directory given any other criteria, e.g. its full pathnames from the top-level search path:

```bsh
find . -type d -path './some/dir/avoid_this_directory_please' -prune -o \
    -type f -print
```

Comment: i was going to write the same thing, slightly differently, as `find . \( -type d -name 'avoid_this_directory_please' -prune \) -o \( -type f -print \)`, but I like your syntax better.  Thanks.

Comment: @TimKennedy You would probably need the parens if you wanted to do `find . -type d \( -name "A" -o -name "B" \) -prune -o -type f -print`.

Comment: good point.  i don't even know when/where I learned to do it with the parentheses.  that age is lost in the mists of time. :)

Comment: This will of course prune off any directories called `avoid_this_directory_please` anywhere in the tree, not just top level ones. `-path` would allow for more control in that, as the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) ([quoted below](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/350092/170373) by Xen2050) states.

Comment: I did not know that `-prune` considered everything after the first `find` argument, including `-type` and was puzzled at failing to prune directories with `find / -type f -path /proc -prune -o -name foo -print`. Seeing both `-type d` and `-type f` in the same command is what made it click for me. Now I finally feel confident in using `find`, thanks.

Answer (score 14):

To avoid a directory try the -path test:

```
find . -type f ! -path '*/avoid_this_directory_please/*'
```

Comment: Note that while it will prevent files inside `avoid_this_directory_please` from being selected (unless their path contain invalid characters), it will not stop `find` from descending in there. That's why `-prune` is better here.

Comment: This is sooooo much better than using `prune`. I always have to read for half an hour to figure out specifying what I don't want for find and then pair with OR logic to obtain the files I want.

Comment: @Merlin It obviously depends on what you want to achieve. With `-prune`, `find` won't even look in the selected paths, while with `! -path`, it would still enter the path and examine everything.

Answer (score 9):

From `man find`, in the `-path` section, apparently combining the other 2  answers

```
To  ignore a whole directory tree, use -prune rather than
checking every file in the tree.  For example, to skip the directory
`src/emacs'  and  all  files and directories under it, and print the
names of the other files found, do something like this:

          find . -path ./src/emacs -prune -o -print
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
find -name "*.js" -not -path "./directory/*"
```

Comment: This works if only you are looking for one extension type. The following will fail:

`find -name "*.js" -o -name "*.css" -not -path "./directory/*"`