# How to exclude/hide a directory from a command (find command or else)?

Tags: bash, find, path, search, firejail

How to exclude a folder or path from a command or application in general?

I am trying to exclude a path from `find` command but available possibilities like `prune` option explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350085/is-it-possible-to-exclude-a-directory-from-the-find-command) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109900/find-prune-does-not-ignore-specified-path) makes the command a little more complicated to achieve advanced search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For any command or application**

Linux namespace can be used easily with [firejail](https://firejail.wordpress.com/) like the following example

```
firejail --noprofile --quiet --blacklist=/path/to/exclude command-or-app
```

**Alternative way to exclude directory from `find`**

```
firejail --noprofile --quiet --blacklist=/path/to/exclude find /search/location -name am-looking-for-this
```

Note that this method will deny access to `/path/to/exclude`, find command will print stderr with `access denied` and exit status will not be 0. `2>/dev/null` can be used at the end of the command to hide stderr if needed, but keep in mind that this can hide other important errors as well. Other additional implementation like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42841/how-to-skip-permission-denied-errors-when-running-find-in-linux) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762348/how-can-i-exclude-all-permission-denied-messages-from-find) may be used as well.

**Find command:**

Options available within `find` command are explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350085/is-it-possible-to-exclude-a-directory-from-the-find-command), [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109900/find-prune-does-not-ignore-specified-path) and the following example:

```
find . -path ./exclude/this -prune -o -print
```