# copying specific files to different directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, rsync

I am trying to find files with specific extensions and copy or rsync it to another hard drive / directory

```
sudo find . \( -type f \( -iname '*.jpg' -o -iname "*png" -o -iname "*mov" -o -iname "*mp3" -o -iname "*mp4" -o -iname "*swf" -o -iname "*avi" \) -exec rsync {} ~/test/dest/ \; \)
```

and shell output is this:

```
cp: './dest/DSC_0085.JPG' and '/home/sanz/test/dest/DSC_0085.JPG' are the same file
cp: './dest/DSC_0086.avi' and '/home/sanz/test/dest/DSC_0086.avi' are the same file
```

and so on...

Why does it keep telling me that what I'm copying and where I'm trying to copy are the same file, even though they are in different directors. this makes no sense.

I'm also trying different command variant, but it also doesn't work as I wanted it to work:

```
sudo find . -type f -iname '*.jpg' -o -name "*png" -o -name "*mov" -o -name "*mp3" -o -name "*mp4" -o -name "*swf" -o -name "*avi" -exec rsync -ah --progress {} ~/test/dest \;
```

It copies ONLY avi files and completely ignores others. It is just strange to me how the same command without -exec normally outputs all the specifically labelled files, but when I want it to work with copying command it only reads/copies avi files.

Comment: Are you sure the output belongs to the first command (`cp` vs. `rsync`)? 
The output is understandable if you ran the command with `cp` in the `test` directory. 
Source and destination of the files are the same. Related: [Is it possible to exclude a directory from the find command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350085/is-it-possible-to-exclude-a-directory-from-the-find-command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running the command in `/home/sanz/test` and then finding the files with the names that are specified anywhere inside which includes the subdirectory `dest` which `find` identifies as `./dest`. That is the same directory as `~/test/dest/` and  `/home/sanz/test/dest/` so you are effectively trying to copy the directories and files into themselves.

If you want to find and copy the files inside of `/home/sanz/test` into `~/test/dest`, then you need to use the `-prune` option to exclude `/home/sanz/test/dest`:

```
sudo find . -path ./dest -prune -o \( -type f \( -iname '*.jpg' -o -iname "*png" -o -iname "*mov" -o -iname "*mp3" -o -iname "*mp4" -o -iname "*swf" -o -iname "*avi" \) -exec rsync {} ~/test/dest/ \; \)
```

Comment: oh that works too i suppose tnx :D

Answer (score 0):

So as it turns out if you copy files from directory to that directory's sub-directory it counts as if you copy same files at same dir as Freddy says. So I created directory somewhere else and after more smashing my head to a keyboard later I created this code:

```
sudo find ~/test/ \( -type f \( -iname '*.jpg' -o -iname "*png" -o -iname "*mov" -o -iname "*mp3" -o -iname "*mp4" -o -iname "*swf" -o -iname "*avi" \) -exec rsync {} ~/dest/ \; \)
```

This worked like charm. I do not have terminology for these techy things, but I hope yall understand me.

Comment: It is not that it counts as if it is the same file. It is the same file. You copied the file to a sub-directory, then found it there, and tried to copy it again. If it must be a sub-directory, then you need to use an exclude as part of the search.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I feel stupid now... Thanks to you too :*

Comment: That is the feeling of learning. When you feel like that, it is in comparison with your new state. Keep learning.