# Why does to order of the parameters affect the files found by `find`?

Tags: find

I found this weird behavior in `find`. Depending on the order of the parameters to `find` it finds different files.

For example, I have a directory tree with the following content.

```
.
├── configure.ac
├── Makefile.am
└── src
    ├── hello.c
    └── Makefile.am
```

if I run

```
find -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.[chS]' -print0 | xargs -0 echo
```

It lists

```
./src/hello.c
```

And if I run

```
find -name '*.[chS]' -o -name '*.cpp' -print0 | xargs -0 echo
```

It doesn't list anything. Notice that the only thing I changed is the order of the file name.

Can anyone explain why the second command doesn't list any files?

Comment: Almost duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/102191/22565

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-print0` action gets bound only to the second `-name` "filter" (test in find parlance), so it will only print out something if the second filter matches. This is because the default operator in the find expression is `and`, and binds tighter than `or` (`-o`). i.e. your second expression is evaluated as:

```
find -name '*.[chS]' -o \( -name '*.cpp' -print0 \) | xargs -0 echo
```

Try grouping the filters:

```
find \( -name '*.[chS]' -o -name '*.cpp' \) -print0 | xargs -0 echo
```

You could also do this if you felt like it:

```
find -name '*.[chS]' -print0 -o -name '*.cpp' -print0 | xargs -0 echo
```

Comment: Huh, that would also explain why giving `-print0` as the first parameter lists all the files. Makes sense, but it's also a bit unexpected. Thanks a lot :)