# `find -type l` matches file while `-type l -o -type f` does not, but only with explicit `-print`

Tags: find, symlink, gnu

I'm using GNU's `find`.

I've simplified my problem to this shell session:

```
$ mkdir t
$ cd t
$ touch a 
$ ln -s a b
$ find -type l
./b
$ find -type l -o -type f
./a
./b
$ find -type l -print
./b
$ find -type l -o -type f -print
./a
```

Maybe it's the fact that I'm very sleepy, but 2 things don't make sense to me:

- Isn't `true OR false == true`? How is it that adding `-o -type f` causes `find` to stop matching `./b`, despite `-type l` matching?
- The manual page says that `-print` is the default expression, so how is it that a file is printed when it's not mentioned, but omitted when it is?

This also happens when using `-printf` (what I actually need); I imagine other expressions are affected, too.

Comment: This too: [`find` with multiple `-name` and `-exec` executes only the last matches of `-name`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102191/find-with-multiple-name-and-exec-executes-only-the-last-matches-of-nam)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
find -type l -o -type f -print
```

you’ve specified an action, so the default no longer applies. But `-printf` here is bound to `-type f` because “and” has a higher precedence than “or”; you can think of this as equivalent to

```
find \( -type l \) -o \( -type f -print \)
```

To process both links and files in the same way, you need to group the tests:

```
find \( -type l -o -type f \) -print
```

Comment: Now it makes sense why the manpage refers to `-print` as an expression; I had no idea actions could be mixed with predicates like `-type`, so I didn't know there were implicit `-a`s in there too. I'm accepting this answer as soon as the system lets me.