# GNU find: Using -o (or) and -print0 in same command does not give expected results

Tags: find

TL;dr: How do I properly combine the `-print0` option in `find` with the `-o` option to match multiple patterns? (The use case is to pass into `xargs -0`)

Example:

```
find . -print0 -name "File*.dat" -o -name "Data*.txt"
```

```
find . -print0 -name "File*.dat" -o -print0 -name "Data*.txt"
```

Both of these return *every file* in the directory.

```
find . -name "File*.dat" -o -name "Data*.txt" -print0
```

This returns *only* files matching the second pattern (`Data*.txt`).

How can I do this properly, and why does this happen?

Comment: also this one: [`find` with multiple `-name` and `-exec` executes only the last matches of `-name`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/102191/170373), doesn't matter if the action is `-exec` or `-print0`

Answer (score -1):

You have quoting problems, and a grouping problem. Using "`"`" invites the shell to do a wildcard match. If you have a matching file or in the current directory, the wildcard will be replaced. Use "`'`" instead.
Grouping is done with parentheses "`()`" which need to be shell escaped.
Your command should be.

```
find . \( -name 'File*.dat' -o -name 'Data*.txt' \) -print0
```

Read `man find`.

Comment: Quoting prevents filename expansion, [even in double quotes](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_03) (try running `echo "*"`).